# Browser like functions in a webpage?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I want my site to have similar navigation to a browser. I want visitors to be able to right click on one of my links/articles and have the option to open a new tab and have the page load in the same page. Here is the concept site I want to work with [link](http://jsbin.com/uruto4/).

Comment: Please clarify a little more on how what you want is different from the native browser controls.  I don't follow

Comment: its not different, i just want the links to open in the same page and not externally. Reason i have my reasons. what code do i need to put in my right mouse click menu, to first know its a link and then when user clicks it opens a knew tab in my page instead of the browsers. thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447321/adding-to-browser-context-menu

Comment: Ill be using a custom jquery menu for the right click but i dont know what code i need to add to the menu so it opens the link in a new tab

Answer (score 1):

Well, then try to use dynamically injected `<iframe>`. Especially when using [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) it could be very easy solution. You must also somehow manipulate the links inside the  content... look at [this link](http://huuah.com/jquery-and-iframe-manipulation/) if it helps, hope you won't have problems with ["same origin policy"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use some ajax function to load content from the new page into the tab.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this would be a good scenario to use a AJAX, for ease of use I would recommend [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).