# Adding to contextmenu programmatically

Tags: javascript, contextmenu

I am trying to add to the context menu programmatically in Javascript.
The model I'm using is vsync's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9293946/322537

And I am changing it into Javascript. What I have you can see in this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/pB76y/

```
..
```

As you can see, if you right click the upper image you can see the new context menu 'View Plate Thumbnail'.
But if you change the id of the menu from 'menu_from_image' to 'menu_from_image_js' (which is the javascript version), then you should get the lower image behaving the same way. But it doesn't.
Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had everything right but it seems that you weren't setting the attribute on the DIV in a way that the browsers was recognizing. Instead of using

```
cmenu.contextmenu = 'menu_for_image_js';
```

I altered it to be:

```
cmenu.setAttribute('contextmenu','menu_for_image_js');
```

I've created a JS Fiddle that shows the change based on your example: http://jsfiddle.net/pB76y/1/