# How to add a new option in addition to existing right-click menu in the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, plugins

Need some help in adding a customized option when i right click from any browser. please note: I am not looking for 'context menu'. Looking for adding the option to existing right-click menu. (Image attached).

Sample_image

[image]

Comment: it depends on browser.https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Add_a_Context_Menu_Item

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4447356/1848140

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding to browser context menu?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447321/adding-to-browser-context-menu)