# How to edit the right click menu of Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, registry

I want to edit the right click of Chrome and add a shortcut to send to a number on Whatsapp. I already have an app that modified the menu to be able to call from a Samsung phone. I'm looking for a way to add more buttons

[image]

I'm not looking for a way to do it from my website or Chrome extension.
There is a similar question that does not relate to my problem here:
[Adding to browser context menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447321/adding-to-browser-context-menu). It does not solve my problem, I'm looking for a way to edit the entire Chrome right click menu, the same way that the "Call from Samsung Phone" option is being populated.

Answer (score 0):

When developing a Chrome extension, you can interact with and add items to the context menu.

More information [in the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/contextMenus/)

Comment: I don't think that the current "call from samsung phone" is coming from a chrome extension, I'm looking for a way to add it in the same way

Comment: Hi, the "Call from ..." is probably a built-in feature between Chrome Desktop and Chrome mobile installed on your phone. You might find with a Chrome extension a way to emulate that behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

you can create your own right click, with all the buttons and actions you want.
first you listen to the this event:

**contextmenu**

then you create your own menu with html and css. if you need a full example, this is a vanilla js example by [ryanmorr](https://codepen.io/ryanmorr):

```
var menu = document.querySelector('.menu');

function showMenu(x, y){
    menu.style.left = x + 'px';
    menu.style.top = y + 'px';
    menu.classList.add('menu-show');
}

function hideMenu(){
    menu.classList.remove('menu-show');
}

function onContextMenu(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    showMenu(e.pageX, e.pageY);
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown, false);
}

function onMouseDown(e){
    hideMenu();
    document.removeEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown);
}

document.addEventListener('contextmenu', onContextMenu, false);
```

to see the full code visit: https://codepen.io/ryanmorr/pen/JdOvYR

Comment: I'm looking for something on my PC, not in the website code, I want to interact with all the websites and not with sites that I have access to their code