# Make 'Open in new tab' available on elements different than anchor

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Using a browser, I often use `Right click -> Open in a new tab` (or click with mouse scroll). I'm developing a website right now, and I noticed this option is available only on `<a>` elements, on `<button>` or other panels it's just not there, even if they have a link/click events.

```html
<a [routerLink]="my-url">...</a> //works
<mat-card [routerLink]="my-url">...</mat-card> //doesnt work
<button [routerLink]="my-url">...</button> //doesnt work
```

I changed all my buttons to anchors and it works there, no problems. But I cannot do that with `mat-card` or other panels. Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: i don't believe so.

Comment: Users who use screen readers will likely have a hard time interacting with your site if you make random elements behave like links but are not also `role="link"` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/link_role I would suggest that if you want a link you keep it an `<a>` tag to not confuse screen reader users.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding to browser context menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447321/adding-to-browser-context-menu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML, only the anchor tags are meant to carry links. The target attribute is dedicated to anchor tags. Therefore, web browsers do not identify the target tag even if you add it to other tags. So the answer is no.

In Angular's client-side routing, you can switch the route using [routerLink]. Unless you can trigger a new tab from Angular itself, this cannot be handled by any HTML tag other than anchors.